# is there a way to run C code designed for an embedded micro-controller on a normal computer?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded

I have a C code which is written for an ATmega16 chip, and it is full of keywords like :

`flash, eeprom, bit`

and macros(?) like

```
interrupt [TIM1_OVF] void timer1_ovf_isr(void)
```

that come before function signatures.

Now what I want to do is write and run unit tests that verify the correctness of the logic of the controller unit and I want to be able to run these tests on any computer and not need to have the "device" that the code represents.

I searched a lot and came across "abstracting the hardware" and "replacing them with stubs" kind of solutions, but I'm not sure how I can abstract something like "**interrupt [TIM1_OVF]**" in the code!

I was wondering if there any special tools that provide the environment for running these sorts of codes?

And also if I am going at it wrong, can anybody point me in the right direction? giving that changing or rewriting (!) the micro-controller's code might not be an option?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: One way we've used was to abstract all possible hw related things to run the entire code on PC. Was kind of a simulation. So you have to abstract EEPROM access with a system file, HW timer interrupts with system timers, UARTs with system COM ports. You don't need to rewrite entire code but only abstract those HW related parts. AFAIK there is no automated tool to do this for you. Also beware that the application timing is very different on PC as there is another CPU and speed.

Comment: @tk_ so the first question that comes to mind is how can I abstract the interrupt timer, and the second is I have to do this for every microcontroller that I use, like if I use ATmega32, I have to do all those things again?

Comment: It depends on what IDE you will use to create such simulation. We've used VS2005 C++ to do this. However, I've just used this simulation and made some minor changes, not written this app, so I cannot say much more. To do this yourself, you must be familiar with the IDE and know how to write system timer events etc. You can then abstract the timer interrupt with single ifdef, e.g. #ifdef SIMULATION ... #else interrupt [TIM1_OVF] #endif. It is not easy task and yes, the abstraction must be done for every HW peripheral you use. It is much easier if you use HAL libraries (like CMSIS etc.)

Comment: how do you abstract? kinda by definition.  you make a function or macro that performs the platform specific thing (interrupt whatever) and call that from the code under test.  then the stub in the simulator performs the same action but simulator based not real hardware based.

Comment: or use an instruction set simulator, pretty easy to bang one out yourself for that processor, an afternoon or evenings project, or use one of the ones already out there as is or modify to meet your needs.

Comment: Are you sure about `bit`?  AVR does not have bit addressable memory - that seems more likely in an 8051 compiler.  A strictly conforming compiler would precede such extension with `__`.  Either way they are proprietary extensions specific to a particular toolchain - you should specify the compiler in question.

Comment: @Clifford I am not an expert on chips, and my question is not about one single chip and its compiler, although the material i provided for the question might be, and I'm looking for a more general answer than that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are not ISO C code, they are compiler specific extensions, they are not common across AVR compilers let alone architectures.  In many cases they can be worked around by defining macros that require little or no modification of the code.  To make your code portable in any case even across different vendor's AVR compilers it is a good idea to do that in any case, although a combination of techniques may be required.

Most compilers support an "always include" option that allows a header file to be included from the command line with an explicit `#include` directive in the source.  Creating a header with your compatibility macros, and including it either implicitly as described or explicitly in the code is a useful technique.  For example for the issues you have mentioned, you might have:

```
// compatability.h
#if !defined COMPATABILITY_INCLUDE
#define COMPATABILITY_INCLUDE

  #if defined __IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__

    #define INTERRUPT( irq, handler ) __interrupt [irq] void handler(void)

  #elif defined _WIN32

    #define INTERRUPT( irq, handler ) void handler(void)

    #define __flash const
    #define __eeprom const
    #define __bit char
  #else
    #error Unknown toolchain/environment
  #endif 

#endif
```

That will remove the memory location qualifiers from the Win32 code, and define `__bit` as a char.  The interrupt handler macro will turn a handler into a regular function on Win32, but does require your code to be modified, but since every toolchain does this differently, that is perhaps no bad thing.

For example in this case you would change:

```
interrupt [TIM1_OVF] void timer1_ovf_isr(void)
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
INTERRUPT( TIM_OVF, timer1_ovf_isr )
{
    ...
}
```

Note that you should use approapriate target macros in the compatability file - I have guessed at IAR for example; you may be using a different compiler.  Your compiler documentation should specify the available predefined macros, alternatively [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) "project" on Sourceforge is a useful resource.

Some of the transformations may change the code semantically, such as swapping `__bit` for `char` in some cases for example if the bit is assigned a value greater than one, and then compared with 1, the embedded target is likely to yield true, while on the PC build it will not.  It might better be transformed to `_Bool` but your compiler may give warnings about implicit conversions. My suggestions may not necessarily be the best possible transformation either - consult your compiler's manual for the precise semantics and decide how best to transform them to standard C for test builds.

An alternative that preserves proprietary semantics is to run your unit tests in an instruction-set simulator using debugger scripting if available to implement stubs for hardware interaction, however that method makes it impossible to use off-the-shelf unit-testing frameworks such as CUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your toolchain, you may already have AVR simulator available, which would allow you to run your unit tests on any PC.  For example, IAR provides "C-SPY", an AVR simulator that supports a terminal window, can show show register values, can support generation of interrupts, etc.  Assuming you keep your unit sizes reasonable, you do not need significant infrastructure or stubbed interfaces to make this work.

One large benefit of running unit tests on your target platform (with your target compiler) is that you can account for any particular behaviors that will be caused by the platform (endianness, word size, compiler or library peculiarities, etc), compared to running in a PC environment.